# Encountering Issues with 'npm install' and 'node install' Commands - Seeking Help to Resolve Dependencies and Installation Problems

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, runtime-error

when I install node modules or node throw this error . This issues see after I try change node version.
[show this error when I install npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHu0M.png)  
[show this error when I run my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1iUV.png)

I want know what is this error . This error I see first time in my 1.5 years developing career

Comment: Means that platform-dependent package wasn't installed for one reason or another. ". This issues see after I try change node version" - looks like the reason. It's unknown what's your project, what's your node version, what's your machine, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask